# Python Pivot - Adding calculation row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pivot-table

I am exploring if it possible to create a calculation or total row which uses the column value based on matching a specified index value.  I am quite new to Python so I am not sure if it is possible using pivots. See pivot I want to replicate below.

As you can see in the image above, I want the **Ordered** Row to be the calculation row.  This will minus the **Not Ordered** Row value of each column from the **Grand Total**.

Is it possible in Python to Search the index, specifying criteria (E.g "Not Ordered") and loop through the columns to calculate the "Ordered Row"?

[image: Example Pivot]

Comment: please provide some example data on which you would like to pivot. If the "not ordered" is a specific label and you're pivoting on those labels, it of course would be included. In the other case, consider this is some NULL Data, you can pass an option to also group by `Nan`s. Whatoever, without more information on what exactly you want to achieve, probably with some example data, we can't help you.

Comment: .. the example data is in the figure. Therefore: the checked box "copy/paste" is disabled... /cry.

Comment: Thank You @ZF007.  That should make the post a lot clearer to understand.